# My listView is not clickable but works when I press enter in emulator?

Tags: android, xml, listview

Not sure whats going on but my custom adapter items(one imageview and 2 textviews) in my listview are not clickable when I use my phone. The weird part is if I press enter in the emulator it focuses and clicks through to the next activity which is what I want to do when I touch it.There is no focus or anything done when I press the list view object on my physical device. Im new to android development and am using constraint layout and the tutorials ive been using use relative layout. here is my code:

List class:

```
 ProductListAdapter adapter = new ProductListAdapter(this, R.layout.content_list,products);

        //hook up listview to adapter
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        //4. to click on idividual items and pass to details view
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                //make an intent
                Intent intent = new Intent(ListActivity.this,DetailsActivity.class);

                startActivity(intent);
```

here is the xml from my list context layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.admin.study2.ListActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_list"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"

    >



    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        tools:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/clothImage"
        android:layout_width="87dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/priceText"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/listView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/listView"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"


        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="211dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="211dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:text=""
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/listView"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/priceText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:text=""
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.69"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/listView"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nameText"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: So actually what u want to do u want to make it clickable or not?

Comment: Yeah I want to make it clickable

Comment: What happens when not using the debugger? Are you stuck at a breakpoint somewhere?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion im not debugging im just using my device. On my android phone I cant click on my list items. Its supppost to be able to focus and be clickable and move onto the next activity but nothing happens

Comment: fixed the issue layout_width and height have to be set to wrap content in order for this to work

Comment: Have any tried other layout instead of constraint?

Comment: Ok u have set it 0dp right?

Comment: I put  wrap_content value for layout_height and width on  the listview

Comment: no I didnt try any other layouts but it will work for both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed the issue layout_width and layout_height both have to be set to wrap content in listview. In my previous they were set to zero

```
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_list">



    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"


        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/clothImage"
        android:layout_width="87dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/priceText"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/listView"


        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/listView"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="211dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="211dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:text=""
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/listView"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        android:focusable="false"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/priceText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:text=""
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.69"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/listView"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nameText"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        android:focusable="false"
        />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```